Closed-form for $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz$
RMM mathematical magazine question:
$$I=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz=?$$
By symmetry
$$I=\frac18\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz$$
Let us consider the solid $S:$$0\leq x\leq1$, $0\leq y\leq x$, $y\leq z\leq 1.$ There are 24 pieces like this piece and by symmetry and $\frac{24}8=3,$
$$I=3\iiint_S\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz.$$
Converting to cylindrical coordinates looks nice:
$$I=3\int_0^{\frac\pi 4}\int_0^{\sec\theta}\int_{r\sin\theta}^1 r\sqrt{r^2+z^2}dzdrd\theta.$$
But, I gave up after İ performed the first iteration.
What do you think about my way? Can this integral be evaluated?
Thanks in advance.

You should not use this cylindrical  transformaition but the polar transfomation instead $x = r\cdot \cos(\theta), y = r\cdot \sin(\theta) \sin(\varphi), y = r\cdot \sin(\theta) \cos(\varphi)$

@NN2 You mean spherical? Would it be better?

@BobDobbs At least $(x,y,z) \mapsto \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ has a spherical symmetry.

@Andreas: This question doesn't require a particular method to solve it, like the question you have mentioned.

@FDP True. My point is that the cited question has answers which SOLVE the problem addressed by OP, so we do not need do treat OP's question again.

I see. It is solved by a famous theorem. Thanks for the comments.

Mathematica says: $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi }{24}+\frac{1}{3} \ln \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)+\frac{1}{72} \ln \left(3650401+2107560 \sqrt{3}\right)\approx 0.960592$

@MariuszIwaniuk https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282%2B%5Csqrt3%29%5E12
